# Android Realm flexibility

Tags: android, realm

looking for a database framework to use in a library I'm designing, I stepped with Realm.

Although is a very good ORM I think it doesn't cover some of the needs a lot of people have when implementing it.

As it does not allow inhetirance, how can I make such a simple thing as creating a caching-expiration based model with Realm? Say, for example, I want all my objects in Realm have two fields: **Date lastUpdate** and **static long expirationTime** and before every call to the API I will check if the object has expired to gather results from cache or from network. The only way to achieve this is copying the fields in all the classes and then I could not even make it generic, as I would have to explicity gettheir fields by type (I couldn't have a generic class for checking if objects has expired for example, without relying on reflection).

So my question is... 
I'm doing a misuse of Realm or I can't really achieve this behavior?

Comment: Never used Realm before. But a quick google search landed me on [this](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/940) page. Are you sure you are using the latest version of Realm?

Comment: you can use interfaces in the latest version of Realm

Comment: @Much Overflow My bad, I didn't mention that I'm using Realm for Android, not for iOS where I see it is possible to use inhetirance. [link](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/761).

Comment: @Ilya Tretyakov I think this approach is a little tricky, because using interfaces would allow to generify transactions with the model but I still need to declare the same fields in all the model objects. Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: We are eventually going to support inheritance and polymorphism (see https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/761) but in the mean time you can use composition instead, which works quite well with the graph-like properties of Realm.